# GoogleMaps Android SDK key restrictions for multiple productFlavors using react-native, react-native-config

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a react-native app that uses react-native-maps.  It works great for my initial product flavor with package name like:

com.package

I've recently add another product flavor.  I'm a bit at a loss as to how to identify the package of the new flavor in the google dashboard using a package name and sha1.

The new flavor uses a different applicationId and an additional applicationSuffix (this was a mistake, but it is what it is).  When I try to identify the package with either the new applicationId, or the applicaitonId + suffix, with the sha1 for the app, the requests never get through (at least I think, the map is blank, and there are no pings in the dashboard).

I've also tried to define the api key with a manifestPlaceholders props in defaultConfig, to no avail.

There's also the wrinkle that I'm using react-native-config to split configurations, but I don't think it's the issue.

Has anyone dealt with this?

Comment: Can you please clarify what the issue is and share the relevant code? Do you need help restricting your API key? If you're using Maps SDK for Android please [follow this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#fingerprint).